# mysql query for finding names include special character single quotes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for an SQL statement that will return only rows of my table whose Name field contains special characters (single quotes).

I used

```
  SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE Name REGEXP '"$'
```

What do i miss to put here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaaa7/1)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test(name varchar(10));

insert into test
values('aaa '''' bb'),('bsbds');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from test
where name regexp "'"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaaa7/1/0)**:

```
|      NAME |
-------------
| aaa '' bb |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE Name like "%\'%"
```

Answer (score 1):

For single quotes alone

```
select * from `table` WHERE Name REGEXP "'";
```

If you need more special symbols like `' % $`

```
select * from `table` WHERE Name REGEXP "['%$]";
```